# Python Idle Symbol Completion

Tags: python-idle

I'm currently using the standard python idle (downloaded from official website), but it does not automatically complete symbols (like { } or [ ]).
Can it do this?

Comment: What do you mean "it does not automatically complete symbols"? Python's "Integrated DeveLopment Environment" (IDLE) is quite lacking in terms of modern IDEs, if you're looking for fancy code completion tools you may be disappointed. You may want to look into JetBrains PyCharm IDE.

Comment: I mean that I type "(" and I want it to automatically write ")"

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned the official python IDE is quite limited. This feature is not supported natively.

Comment: do you know any compiler which looks compact (similar to Dev-C++ for example) and which has this feature?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I'd recommend JetBrains PyCharm IDE.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE does not currently do auto-closing of openers.  There is a [proposal](https://bugs.python.org/issue18875) on the python issue tracker and a git [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/3520).

IDLE does match (, [, and { openers either when one types the corresponding ), ], or } closer or when one requests such matching.